# How to make ubuntu work from pendrive

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, usb-drive

How to make ubuntu as pendrive bootable after downloading it from the website? and how much capacity pendrive will be ideal?

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows**

Refer to the official Ubuntu documentation here - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. You can find the instructions and ideal usb siz there.

**If you are on a Linux Machine**

You can use `unetbootin`.